# whats wrong with this wrapper class with for loop

Tags: java, class, methods, wrapper

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Calculation C=new Calculation();
    int i;
    for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
    {
         C.m[i]=Integer.valueOf(args[i]);        
         //assignment of command line arguments with the array//        
    }
    C.display();
}
```

this gives error of "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5" with the input of command line arguments as 10 20 30 40 50 60
Please help me

Comment: What kind of class is ''Calculation''? Concluding from the error message, the Array "m" of the Calculation class has a size smaller than 5. You cannot access the element at index 5, as indices start at 0 and the 5th element would be at index 4.

Comment: Not enough info to tell

Comment: The loop assumes that both arrays (`args[]` and `C.m[]`) have at least 6 elements.  It would appear that at least one of them does not.

Comment: whats the size of `m[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The array m inside of C has less than 6 elements. During the first time that the loop executed you are trying to access the element C.m[5] which is the 6th element in the array. The same could also be true for args[].